# Where is the "Stop" button in Eclipse? - NOT RESOLVED

Tags: eclipse

in Eclipse Version 2022-12 I can not seem to find "Stop" button. [image: Stop button] It was in toolbar for Launch, now it is disappeared.

Now, I see toolbar without Stop buttons:

[image: Without stop buttons]

And when I customize Perspective, I can not have option to add Stop button:

[image: Customize perspective]

I use "Java EE" perspective.

Thank you for an advice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the toolbar at all? If the whole toolbar is missing, you can do *"window > appearance > show toolbar"*.

Or is it that you see the toolbar but just the stop button is missing? Then you can do *"window > perspective > Reset Perspective"*.

Are you sure it's not just grayed out? if you're not running anything (or if all your programs finished and terminated), it's a gray square, like this:

[image: grayed stop button image]

It might just be that your perspective doesn't have a stop button in it's toolbar. You can change to an appropriate perspective by doing: *"window > perspective > open perspective > Java"* for a plain Java editor; but I do some web development, so I do *"window > perspective > open perspective > other perspective > Java EE"*.

You might have accidentally deleted the stop button from your perspective, in which case you can customize a perspective to add back the stop button:
*"window > perspective > customize perspective"*, make sure "Launch" is checked in your toolbar structure, then "Apply" and "Close".

Or, if you didn't want to customize your perspective at all, try *"window > perspective > Reset Perspective"*.

Comment: If it's grayed out, it could also be that you have nothing considered stoppable, like a process in the Debug view, selected.

Comment: I added information to first message (two pictures: customize perspective and my actual toolbar). I tried reset perspective and it is without effect for Stop buttons). Stop buttons is missing after I started the newest Eclipse 2022-12. The orders version have the Stop buttons.